# heroku run worker (error)

Tags: python, heroku

Can someone please tell me what I can do to fix this problem? The app was deployed successfully to heroku but it wouldn't run when I tested it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: please add the relevant code from ebboks.py which causes this exception.  Without adding that, your question is not complete and users won't be able to tell the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be reproduced by following python code:

```
import random
random.choice(range(0))
```

Check a value of the variable `ODDS` in your `local_settings.py` file.